# Is there a way to print all the information in a certain amount of commits in TortoiseSVN/subversion?

Tags: tortoisesvn, printing, commit, logging

I want to be able to print out all of the changes to the code since a certain date. Without manually copy and pasting the information from all the commit logs, is there an easier way to get all this information into a central location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn log -r {DATE} > myfile.txt`

Comment: this will pull ALL of the commit logs for that date? 

What if I need, say a week's worth of commit logs?

Comment: It will give you the logs SINCE that date. I believe you can put a second date in there `svn log -r {startDate} {endDate} > myfile.txt` and it will return the changes between those two dates